# System of diophantine equations related to Ozanam's problem

Tags: diophantine-equations

Could you please help with finding of general solution of diophantine system for rational a, b, c, d

$(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=A^2$

$(a^2-b^2)(c^2-d^2)=B^2$

for some rational A and B.

This is related to Ozanam's problem.

Comment: I think the field of solutions of this system should be similiar to $(a^4-b^4)(c^4-d^4)=X^2$ does this make sense?

Comment: Not necessarily. A solution to $(a^4-b^4)(c^4-d^4) = x^2$ is $a,b,c,d =1,\,3,\,31,\,49$, but it does ***not*** solve $ (a^2\pm b^2) (c^2\pm d^2) = \square$.

Comment: Yes. Sure. Obviously the set of solutions of $(a^4-b^4)(c^4-d^4)=X^2$ is larger. Would be interesting to get the general solution for this equation also. May be we can filter out the solutions of $(a^2\pm b^2) (c^2\pm d^2) = \square$ from there.

Comment: And also I have found the following article with some set of solutions,  but not sure if this is a general solution. http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0315086084710056/1-s2.0-S0315086084710056-main.pdf?_tid=6959af9a-001f-11e6-b92b-00000aacb35f&acdnat=1460404739_c629833631b91c236c761a6de7b27cfd page 15.

Comment: It turns out this system $S_1$ is just a particular solution to the _Mengoli Six-Square Problem_ (MSP). Are you interested only in $S_1$, or is your interest in the broader MSP?

Comment: Actally I am interested in only $S_1$ because of the task I am currently working on. From this paper I have found the following solutions: $c=-{k}{a}( {a}^{8}+6\,{a}^{4}{b}^{4}-3\,{b}^{8});  
d=-{k}{b}( 3\,{a}^{8}-6\,{a}^{4}{b}^{4}-{b}^{8}) $. But not sure if this is the general solution of this system.